# Linkage error with CXF client

Tags: maven, wso2, osgi

I am trying to set up an application on an ESB server. We have an OSGi bundle with all of the dependencies we'd need, but we're now having a weird problem. On runtime the server will be unable to instantiate the CXF client for our app server. The stack trace is

```
java.lang.LinkageError: loader constraint violation: when resolving method "javax.xml.ws.Service.<init>(Ljava/net/URL;Ljavax/xml/namespace/QName;)V" the class loader (instance of org/eclipse/osgi/internal/baseadaptor/DefaultClassLoader) of the current class, mil/sddc/fltmgt/ws/api/FleetManagementWSServiceService, and the class loader (instance of <bootloader>) for resolved class, javax/xml/ws/Service, have different Class objects for the type <init> used in the signature
            at mil.sddc.fltmgt.ws.api.FleetManagementWSServiceService.<init>(FleetManagementWSServiceService.java:39)
            at mil.sddc.ibs.mediators.fleetManagement.TestClient.mediate(TestClient.java:28)
            at org.apache.synapse.mediators.ext.ClassMediator.mediate(ClassMediator.java:78)
            at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:77)
            at org.apache.synapse.mediators.AbstractListMediator.mediate(AbstractListMediator.java:47)
            at org.apache.synapse.mediators.base.SequenceMediator.mediate(SequenceMediator.java:131)
            at org.apache.synapse.rest.Resource.process(Resource.java:297)
            at org.apache.synapse.rest.API.process(API.java:341)
            at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.dispatchToAPI(RESTRequestHandler.java:76)
            at org.apache.synapse.rest.RESTRequestHandler.process(RESTRequestHandler.java:63)
            at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.Axis2SynapseEnvironment.injectMessage(Axis2SynapseEnvironment.java:220)
            at org.apache.synapse.core.axis2.SynapseMessageReceiver.receive(SynapseMessageReceiver.java:83)
            at org.apache.axis2.engine.AxisEngine.receive(AxisEngine.java:180)
            at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.processNonEntityEnclosingRESTHandler(ServerWorker.java:344)
            at org.apache.synapse.transport.passthru.ServerWorker.run(ServerWorker.java:168)
            at org.apache.axis2.transport.base.threads.NativeWorkerPool$1.run(NativeWorkerPool.java:172)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1145)
            at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:615)
            at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
```

I haven't seen this particular stack trace before but it looks like WSO2's bootup classloader are both providing an instance of FleetManagementWSServiceService, Service, or both, resulting in a conflict.

It sounds like WSO2's bootup classloader and the classloader for my OSGi bundle are both providing FleetManagementWSServiceService, Service, or both. Presumably it would have to be Service, as even if I accidentally had that class in a jar that would be picked up by the bootup classloader the one in the OSGi bundle should always be favored.

The other class, javax.xml.ws.Service, is included in the Java runtime as well as a few other jars. I found a geronimo jaxws jar with it in the endorsed folder on the server and deleted it just in case, but this did not affect the build.

Comment: I do not see CXF involved in this stacktrace. It seems you are using Axis2. Please update your question.

Comment: The only relevancy of CXF is that this exception occurs on instantiation of the CXF client. FleetManagementWSServiceService is an autogenerated CXF service and, as such, extends javax.xml.ws.Service. I believe that the root of the issue is conflicting dependencies in the WSO2 server, but I can't figure out which.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When I posted this I thought the problem came from missing dependencies on the server, but as it turned out we were actually missing dependencies in our OSGi bundle. By including a geronimo-jaxws jar, which contains javax.xml.ws.Service, this issue was resolved.

Near as I can tell the issues with Axis2 and CXF were red herrings. There are still CXF dependencies within the bundle, and the server is still using Axis2 to call our classes. 'Preciate the help, nonetheless!

Answer (score 1):

I assume that you have CXF and Axis2 installed in parallel. This will not work. The stacktrace shows that Axis2 is triggered to start your client but it conflicts with the installed CXF.

So the solution is to only install either Axis2 or CXF.